# How to update a value in a JSON file using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I'm trying to update a value of one of the objects in a json file. The problem is there are several siblings in the same json file with the same key-value pairs.

My **Json** file looks like so:

```
{"LogIns":[
{"Username":"Alfred",
"password":"123",
"Won":0,"Lost":0},
{"Username":"Farrah",
"password":"123",
"Won":0,"Lost":0}]}
```

Each time somebody wins a hand (it's a card game) I need to update the number of games won or lost.

This is the AJAX call to the PHP file:

---

**AJAX:**

```
var username = localStorage.getItem("username"); 

  if(document.getElementById(btnId).value == answer){
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
          console.log("returned:", xhttp.responseText);
        }
      xhttp.open("POST", "leaderboard.php", true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhttp.send("username=" + username + "&won=1");

    }
    else{
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
          console.log(xhttp.responseText);
        }
      xhttp.open("POST", "leaderboard.php", true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhttp.send("username=" + username + "&lost=1");

    }
  setTimeout(reloadPage, 2000);

}
```

You can take my word for it that the HTML is all correct and is not really needed here, but my PHP file looks like so:

**PHP:**

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];

if(isset($_POST['won'])){
    $won = $_POST['won'];
    //echo $won;
}

if(isset($_POST['lost'])){
    $lost = $_POST['lost'];
    //echo $lost;
}
$str = file_get_contents('logins.json'); // Save contents of file into a variable

$json = json_decode($str, true); // decode the data and set it to recieve data asynchronosly - store in $json

foreach($json['LogIns'] as $res){
    if($res['Username']==$username){
        if(isset($won)){
            $add = $res['Won'];
            $add = ($add + $won);
            $res['Won'] = $add;
            echo $res['Won']; 
        }
        else{

            $add = $res['Lost'];
            $add = ($add + $lost);
            $res['Lost'] = $add;
            echo $res['Lost']; 

        }
        break;
    }
}

file_put_contents('logins.json', json_encode($json));

?>
```

The `xhttp.responseText` that is printed to the screen is always ("1"), but when I print_r $json the won or lost field is still 0.

Does anybody know what i'm doing wrong?

Any help as ever would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly: you are updating a temporary item `$res` that is NOT referencing the original array element. In PHP, only objects are passed by reference by default. If you want to pass another variable type by reference, you have to prepend `&` to it.

Some more details here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Quick fix, untested:

```
foreach ($json['LogIns'] as $index => $res) {
    if ($res['Username'] == $username) {
        if (isset($won)) {
            $add = $res['Won'];
            $add = ($add + $won);
            $json[$index]['Won'] = $add; // <-
            echo $res['Won']; 
        }
        else{

            $add = $res['Lost'];
            $add = ($add + $lost);
            $json[$index]['Lost'] = $add; // <-
            echo $res['Lost']; 
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Or you can pass the array item to the loop by reference:

```
foreach ($json['LogIns'] as &$res) { // <-
    if ($res['Username'] == $username) {
        if (isset($won)) {
            $add = $res['Won'];
            $add = ($add + $won);
            $res['Won'] = $add;
            echo $res['Won']; 
        }
        else{

            $add = $res['Lost'];
            $add = ($add + $lost);
            $res['Lost'] = $add;
            echo $res['Lost']; 
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why using `break;` ? Haven't seen that in an if-else statement yet.

Comment: Yeah, did some research, might be useful later on :) Thanks

Comment: Hi Francesco, thanks for that. The second method worked. The first method made the Json file look like so: {"LogIns":[{"Username":"Alfred","password":"123","Won":3,"Lost":0},{"Username":"Farrah","password":"123","Won":0,"Lost":0}],"0":{"Won":4}}

Comment: So it was appending it outside of the object in the Json file. But the second method worked perfectly. I'm not exactly sure what the & done though to make it work. If you have the time could you explain please?

Comment: I added a bit of explanation and a link to the official documentation.

Comment: That's great, thanks again Francesco. Much appreciated!